# Dockerfile - CMD does not run the shell script

Tags: docker, cmd, dockerfile

Ok just learning about creating a Dockerfile and my understanding (which is probably wrong) is that the `CMD` command should be able to run a shell script from within the container once it is placed there.

I am just trying it out with a vanilla apache2 install

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ADD install-apache.sh /Scripts/install-apache.sh
RUN chmod +x /Scripts/install-apache.sh
CMD [/Scripts/install-apache.sh]



RUN echo "Hope this worked!"
```

I have also tried this:

```
CMD ["/Scripts/install-apache.sh"]
```

When I use the `RUN` command it works (without the [ and ])

**So I am a bit lost what the `CMD` is suppose to do.**

I followed the instructions from [http://kimh.github.io](http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/docker/gotchas-in-writing-dockerfile-en/)
and read through the docker docs as well.

**Question:**
How am I using the `CMD` wrong and how should I use it in this scenario?

Answer (score 5):

- `RUN` is executed while you are building an image. This is usually used to install things or perform modifications in the resulting image.
- `CMD` is executed when the container is started. Use this to e.g. start applications.

Also check the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing
>   container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
>   the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT
>   instruction as well.

Comment: Oh so the CMD is run when a user runs the container I am building - 
and RUN is used when I am building it?

Comment: @JeffKranenburg exactly

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian - will accept in a few minutes when SO allows me too :-)

Comment: Yep. You could literally just change `CMD [/Scripts/install-apache.sh]` to `RUN /Scripts/install-apache.sh` and it would do what you're expecting it to. As an example of `CMD`, you'd likely want something like `CMD ["httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]` to automatically start apache for you when the container boots up.

Comment: But i want to run the .sh file on CMD how can i achieve that ?